# How to generate a sequence with periodic $-1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have, trivially, that
$$ 1^n = \{1,1,...\}$$
$$(-1)^n =\{1,-1,1,...\}$$
And further,

$$-3 (\lfloor {\frac{2n^2}{3}}\rfloor ) +2n^2 -1= \{1,1,-1,1,1,-1,...\}$$
But this isn't too clear to generalise. 
My question is, what is the general way to generate a sequence like this, where we have a $(-1)$ appear every, say, $k$ terms?
Can we take advantage of the periodic nature?

Comment: Let $\zeta = e^{2 \pi i/n}$. Then
$$a_k:=1^k + \zeta^k + \zeta^{2k} + \ldots + \zeta^{(p-1)k}
= \begin{cases} n, & k \equiv 0 \bmod n \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
By scaling linearly, you can make this sequence be any constant $A$ for $k \not\equiv 0 \bmod n$
and a different constant $B$ for $k \equiv 0 \bmod n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider
$$u_n = 1-2\lfloor\frac{\cos \left( \frac{2n\pi}{k}\right)+1}{2}\rfloor.$$